# rest ajax sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, rest, ajax

I am trying to apply and use JQuery news ticker from SharePoint list for which I need to use REST Ajax call, I have tried some codes from net but none of them works, so I am confused where to put the code.

I am using SharePoint designer & I am putting code in script editor & content editor.

Can anyone tell where to put the code & How to apply the jquery plugin on that retrieved list items?

I am new in this thing might sound kiddish. thanks in advance.

P>S> :- Can't use visual studio for this task.

Comment: What's the code you are trying to use? It's possible the code is wrong, not that you're putting it in the wrong place.  Code should go in a content editor web part or a script editor web part.  Code should go in `<script>` tags.  You need separate script tags for the jQuery library and the news ticker script (sorry if you already knew that, wasn't sure if you're just new to SharePoint or development in general).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a txt file and add all your script references in that text file and give the reference of txt in web part content link.
[image: content link]

Answer (score 0):

Simple way. Just add a content editor web part to the page ,  give reference to a html file (created through designer) and add ur javascript code into your custom js file, finaly reference these js files on html file.  Add your juery plug reference above the custome js reference.